# Python Decorators and Classes

Tags: python, class, flask, decorator

I am working on a web server using Flask and Flask-Login. It was working until I needed to move it to a class. It is broken because of decorators: before I had the code

```
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
...
@login_required
def control_panel():
    return render_template(...)
```

But this now becomes:

```
class webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_manager = LoginManager(app)

    ...
    @login_required
    def control_panel(self):
        return self.render_template(...)
```

The issue is that I really need to write,

```
@self.login_required
```

But it is not valid syntax. How can I overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to write `@self`?

Comment: Because it won't recognise login_required, as it is part of login_manager, which became self.login_manager

Comment: That makes no sense. It's only `self` if it's an attribute of the class, which it isn't.

Comment: I cannot use @login_required, as it is not defined.

Comment: Then maybe you need to import it.

Comment: In the "before" code, what did `login_manager = LoginManager(app)` have to do with defining `login_required`?

Comment: The class that owns LoginManager also creates the decorator login_required

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your LoginManager creates the decorator, but you could make it work like this:

```
class LoginManager:
    def __init__(self, app):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def login_required(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print "login_required: before"
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print "login_required: after"
        return inner


class Webserver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_manager = LoginManager(app)

    @LoginManager.login_required
    def control_panel(self):
        print "control_panel: called"


app = {}
ws = Webserver()
ws.control_panel()
```

Output:

```
login_required: before
control_panel: called
login_required: after
```

Comment: Some feedback would be nice. Is this working for you? If not, why?

Comment: Sorry! I stopped bothering with the class way because it was to complicated. It's working as before. Thanks anyway though!